# A small probability crash event on sigsegv (segv_access) on the iOS side

Tags: ios, crash

My question is how to locate the specific function instruction that crashed, just like the system function has a crashed assembly instruction stack; or to analyze the possible reasons, I personally think it may be that the * error pointer was released in another thread The wild pointer problem, but how to verify it

Where projectName represents the project name, indicating that it is an internal function of the project, not a system function

The crash stack information is as follows：

Crashed thread ## #0 Thread ##
SIGSEGV
SEGV_ACCERR

From the stack it seems to be a crash caused at startup

```
        0 projectName   -[FlexTemplateManager dataForPath:error:] + 132
        1 projectName   -[FlexTemplateManager dataForPath:error:] + 124
        2 projectName   -[FlexTemplateManager jsonForPath:error:] + 28
        3 projectName   -[FlexTemplateManager dimensionConfig] + 140
        ...
        31 UIKitCore    -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 248
        32 UIKitCore    -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 220
        33 UIKitCore    -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 548
        34 UIKitCore    -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 360
        35 FrontBoardServices   -[FBSSceneImpl _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 436
        36 FrontBoardServices   ___86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.154 + 100
        37 FrontBoardServices   -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 232
        38 FrontBoardServices   ___86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 312
        ...
        42 FrontBoardServices   -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible] + 404
        43 FrontBoardServices   -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28
        44 CoreFoundation   ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
        45 CoreFoundation   ___CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 80
        46 CoreFoundation   ___CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
        47 CoreFoundation   ___CFRunLoopRun + 1080
        48 CoreFoundation   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
        49 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal + 104
        50 UIKitCore    UIApplicationMain + 1936
        51 projectName  main (main.m:21)
        52 libdyld.dylib    _start + 4
```

The specific crash line by calculating the offset "  *error = [NSError errorWithCode:-10 message:@"文件路径为空"]; "

```
    - (NSData *)dataForPath:(NSString *)filePath error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error {
            if (filePath == nil) {
                if (error) {
                    *error = [NSError errorWithCode:-10 message:@"文件路径为空"];
                }
                return nil;
            }
            ...
    }

    + (instancetype)errorWithCode:(NSInteger)code message:(NSString *)message {
        return [NSError errorWithDomain:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey code:code message:message];
    }
```